# Programmatically configuring CDT project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I created a Eclipse plugin with a new project type, creating that project type also adds the C/C++ natures from CDT. Now I want to provide a default configuration for that project type, specifically I want it to be configured to use the CMake4Eclipse build type.

I need to set:

1. current Toolchain
2. current Builder
3. CMake Host OS overrides
4. Source location
5. Environment

For neither of those have I been able to figure out how to set them programmatically. A solution where I have a static default configuration is acceptable.

Comment: Isn't it enough to add the CDT nature and CDT builders and creating the `.cdtproject` file?

Comment: @howlger I managed to add the CDT nature, but where I am stuck is configuring - I guess the builders. It just has the default configuration, I have not been able to set the preferences I want programmatically. Since my project type is always built with cmake, with minimal adjustments necessary (I hope), I want to provide a reasonable default configuration for my project type. Either way, of the three things you mention I only know how to do two. How I set the builder programmatically, I do not know.

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.html#setDescription-org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription-org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. and 2. (setting toolchain & builder) I managed successfully with the following code:

```
// convert to C/C++ project
    CCorePlugin ccore = CCorePlugin.getDefault();
    ccore.convertProjectToNewC(project, ManagedBuildManager.CFG_DATA_PROVIDER_ID, monitor);
    CCorePlugin.getDefault().convertProjectFromCtoCC(project, monitor);

// get toolchain and cmake builder
    IBuilder cmakeBuilder = ManagedBuildManager.getExtensionBuilder("de.marw.cdt.cmake.core.genscriptbuilder");
    IToolChain toolChain = ManagedBuildManager.getExtensionToolChain("cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.base");

// arcane incantations based on org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.wizards.NewMakeProjFromExisting.performFinish()
    ICProjectDescriptionManager pdMgr = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescriptionManager();
    ICProjectDescription projDesc = pdMgr.createProjectDescription(project, false);
    ManagedBuildInfo info = ManagedBuildManager.createBuildInfo(project);
    ManagedProject mProj = new ManagedProject(projDesc);
    info.setManagedProject(mProj);

    CfgHolder cfgHolder = new CfgHolder(toolChain, null);
    IConfiguration config = new Configuration(mProj, (ToolChain) toolChain,
    ManagedBuildManager.calculateChildId(toolChain.getId(), null), cfgHolder.getName());
// set cmake builder
    config.changeBuilder(cmakeBuilder, ManagedBuildManager.calculateChildId(config.getId(), null),
    cmakeBuilder.getName());
// make sure makefile generation is enabled
    config.setManagedBuildOn(true);
    CConfigurationData data = config.getConfigurationData();
    projDesc.createConfiguration(ManagedBuildManager.CFG_DATA_PROVIDER_ID, data);

    pdMgr.setProjectDescription(project, projDesc);
```

Step 3. (cmake configuration) wasn't possible out of the box, the cmake4eclipse plugin does not export the API necessary to change its settings. So I created a fragment that imports and exports the necessary packages. Then it was straightforward to configure with above code in place:

```
ICConfigurationDescription desc = projDesc.createConfiguration(ManagedBuildManager.CFG_DATA_PROVIDER_ID, data);
CMakePreferences cmakePref = ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getOrCreate(desc);
cmakePref.getWindowsPreferences().setGenerator(CmakeGenerator.NMakeMakefiles);
cmakePref.getDefines().add(new CmakeDefine("CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE",CmakeVariableType.STRING,"Release"));
```

Step 4. (setting a source folder) looks like this:

```
  private void setAsSourceFolder(IResource folder, IProject project) throws CoreException {
    ICSourceEntry newEntry = new CSourceEntry(folder.getProjectRelativePath(), null, 0);
    ICProjectDescription des = CCorePlugin.getDefault().getProjectDescription(project, true);

    ICConfigurationDescription[] cfgs = des.getConfigurations();
    for (ICConfigurationDescription cfg : cfgs) {
      cfg.setSourceEntries(new ICSourceEntry[] { newEntry });
    }

    CCorePlugin.getDefault().setProjectDescription(project, des);
  }
```

Comment: In step 3 above, it is not necessary to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. cmake4eclipse automatically sets this depending on CDT's build configuration (Debug or Release) at build-time. If you need programmatic access to the `CMakePreferences`, consider filing a change request on the cmake4eclipse issue tracker.

Comment: @MartinWeber OK I will try that. In any case, I need programmatic access for other options, as well as the generator.